# How do you do two date calculations in one SQL Statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In a SQL Stored Procedure, I need to calculate a date by subtracting 1 month and set the day to the 17th of the month.

I can subtract 1 month with:

```
DATEADD(month,-1, loanFirstPmtDate)
```

But do not know how to also set the day to 17.

How do I do both calculations in one SQL statement?

Example: Loan First Payment Date = ‘03/01/2019’
Subtract 1 month and set day to 17 = ‘02/17/2019’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a date:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = CONVERT(date, GETDATE());
```

--The beginning of this month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), @date);
```

-- The beginning of last month - just subtract a month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, -1, 
  DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), @date));
```

-- Then to get the 17th of last month, just add 16 days:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 16, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, 
  DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), @date)));
```

That will work on 2008 and above. On 2012 you can write it a little shorter:

```
DECLARE @date datetime = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@date), MONTH(@date), 17);
```

If you are doing this for searching, though, and not output, I highly recommend adjusting the date range parameter values, not applying `DATEADD()` operations data in the `loanFirstPmtDate` column.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not always add 16 days. I want to ignore the day value in the date field and set the day to the 17th.

Comment: @DanK that's what my code does. If you find the first of the month (which is easy given any date), the 17th is always 16 days later. I assume you just haven't tried it yet?

Comment: @DanK Be aware that SQL Server 2008 R2 is almost a decade old and falls completely out of even extended support later this year.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I was able to get your code working replacing GETDATE with the Date field.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I was able to get your code working replacing GETDATE with the Date field.

 DATEADD(DAY, 16, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(l.loanFirstPmtDate), l.loanFirstPmtDate))) as [FrirstPmtDate-1MonthDay17]

FirstPmtDate         FrirstPmtDate-1MonthDay17
02/01/2019 00:00 01/17/2019 00:00

p.s. My company will be upgrading SQL Server later this year.

Thanks again